# IFTweetLabel RegexKitLite open UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, hyperlink, regexkitlite

I am using IFTweetLabel and have it to the point were it recognizes links but I am having an awful time opening a webview with the button IFTweetLabel creates. I a running the NSLog and can clearly see it is understanding each link when the button is presses but it will not open the URL for some reason .

Below is the code I am using to show the view and load the string in a webView....which all works besides the loading of the webview.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated! thank you!

```
- (void)handleTweetNotification:(NSNotification *)notification

{
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

CGRect viewFrame = [MainwebView frame];
viewFrame.origin.x = 220;
MainwebView.frame = viewFrame;        

MainwebView.alpha = 1.0; 
web.alpha = 1.0;

MainwebView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
MainwebView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
MainwebView.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0f;
MainwebView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;     



[self.view addSubview:MainwebView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tweetLabel.text]]]; 

NSLog(@"handleTweetNotification: WTF notification = %@", notification);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code which should work well, but also should be cleaned up some:

```
    - (void)handleTweetNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {    

    unichar theChar = [(NSString *)notification.object characterAtIndex:0];
    NSString *theString = (NSString *)notification.object;


    if ( [[NSString stringWithCharacters:&theChar length:1] isEqualToString:@"#"]) {
        DLog(@"This is a hashtag");
        theString = [theString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"%23"];
        NSURL *hashtagURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://twitter.com/#!/search?q=%@", theString]];
        WebViewController *theWebVC = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
        theWebVC.request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:hashtagURL];
        UINavigationController *theNavigationVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theWebVC];
        [self presentModalViewController:theNavigationVC animated:YES];

    }

    if ( [[NSString stringWithCharacters:&theChar length:1] isEqualToString:@"@"]) {
        DLog(@"This is a Mention");
        theString = [theString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@""];
        NSURL *mentionURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://twitter.com/%@", theString]];
        WebViewController *theWebVC = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
        theWebVC.request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:mentionURL];
        UINavigationController *theNavigationVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theWebVC];
        [self presentModalViewController:theNavigationVC animated:YES];

    }
    if ( [[NSString stringWithCharacters:&theChar length:1] isEqualToString:@"h"]) {
        DLog(@"This is a hyperlink");
        theString = [[theString componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSURL *hyperlinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", theString]];
        WebViewController *theWebVC = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
        theWebVC.request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:hyperlinkURL];
        UINavigationController *theNavigationVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theWebVC];
        [self presentModalViewController:theNavigationVC animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The string the user clicked on, is passed onto this method and can be found by using [notification object]. What you are doing in your code is passing all of the text inside your tweetLabel to the webview. Since this isn't a URL, your app will crash. Use this instead:
`[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[notification object]]]];`

You can also NSLog the [notification object] first to make sure it's a URL.